# Мониторинг страницы каждые 5 сек

Tags: java

Помогите реализовать. 
Необходимо мониторить каждые 5 секунд страницу " localhost:9911/star?request=1 " на наличие изменений.
При заходе на эту страницу выдает только одну строку текста " {"stars":100} " вот это значение и надо мониторить. 
И если stars >= 200, то необходимо сделать запрос " localhost:9911/star?transf=2&stars=... " вместо точек поставить значение stars деленное на 100. И затем все заново.

Comment: @jerrym, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Прошу прощения, подскажите как через JSON получить значение в переменную? Или есть более интересный способ реализовать задуманное?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать какую-нибудь библиотеку для работы с JSON (например JSON Simple) или выпилить число ручками, типа так    
String s = "{\"stars\":100}";  
int stars = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(s.indexOf(':') + 1, s.indexOf('}')));

Comment: как она (JSON Simple) в сравнении с [GSON][1]


  [1]: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide